# Accelerated C++ exercise 11-6

Tags: c++, stl

Got  stuck  in the erase function  on ch 11  excercise 11-6. I  have destroyed the objects but I have no idea how to use deallocation from allocator library to return the space.

Please bail me out.
PS : its not homework but I am practising  at home

Below is the  code from Accelerated C++ and after that My modified erase function.
Thanks `

```
template <class T> class Vec
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

    Vec() { create(); }
    explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& t = T()) { create(n, t); }
    Vec(const Vec& v) { create(v.begin(), v.end()); }
    Vec& operator=(const Vec&);
    ~Vec() { uncreate(); }

    T& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](size_type i ) const { return data[i]; }

    void push_back(const T& t)
    {
        if (avail == limit)
        {
            grow();
        }

        unchecked_append(t);
    }

    iterator erase(iterator);
    iterator erase( iterator, iterator );
    void clear();

    size_type size() const { return avail - data; }

    iterator begin() { return data; }
    const iterator begin() const { return data; }

    iterator end() { return avail; }
    const iterator end() const { return avail; }

private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;

    std::allocator<T> alloc;

    void create();
    void create(size_type, const T&);
    void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

    void uncreate();

    void grow();
    void unchecked_append(const T&);
};
```

MY CODE

```
 template <class T> typename Vec<T>::iterator Vec<T>::erase(iterator  first, iterator second )
{
    if( second < first )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Iterator out of bounds.");
    }
    if( first < data || second >= avail )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Iterator out of bounds.");
    }
    iterator last = avail -1 ;
    iterator i = first ;
    iterator j = second ;  
    while( j <= last )
    {
        *i++ = *j++ ;

    }
    // destroy each initilsed space 
    iterator new_avail =  avail -  first + second ;

    std::cout << " end " << end() << std::endl;

    while( avail != new_avail )
    {
        alloc.destroy(--avail ) ;
    }


    // dellocate  space how to do  that ?
    alloc.deallocate( avail -1,  );  // not sure  what to do  here 
    return first ;

}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not deallocate a portion of allocated memory.
That

> alloc.deallocate( avail -1,  );

is no good.

**Edit**

You should not try to mangage allocation in erase.
An option you have is to reallocate it, which will make the erase even more
expensive. A second function could do:

```
iterator shrink(iterator first, iterator last) {

    size_type capacity = (limit - data) - (last - first);

    iterator new_data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
    iterator new_avail = new_data;
    iterator source = data;
    while(source < first)
        // C++11
        alloc.construct(new_avail++, std::move(*source++));
    source = last;
    iterator result = new_avail;
    while(source < avail)
        // C++11
        alloc.construct(new_avail++, std::move(*source++));
    while(data < avail)
        alloc.destroy(--avail);
    data  = new_data;
    avail = new_avail;
    limit = new_data + capacity;

    return result;
}
```

A better option is this standard way. Add an additional constructor, 
 swap and shrink_to_fit:

```
Vec(const_iterator first, const_iterator last) {
    create(first, last);
}

void swap(Vec& other) {
    std::swap(data, other.data);
    ...
}

bool shrink_to_fit() {
    try
    {
        Vec(begin(), end()).swap(*this);
        return true;
    }
    catch(...) {}
    return false;
}
```

Now you can apply multiple operations on the vector and shrink memory consumption finally.

```
 v.erase(a, b);
 v.erase(c, d);
...
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, that one of solutions is to create a new vector with the following size:

```
new_size = old_size - number_of_elements_to_delete
```

Then you copy objects from start to the first erasing object, from last erasing object to the end and then release old vector.

It is not the best solution but the simplest as I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I guess what i am doing is also not bad , I just dont knwo how to use member function deallocate from allocator. So  mostly I need help in that . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's what a [reference page for `std::allocator::deallocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate) has got to say:

> `void deallocate( pointer p, size_type n );`
>
> Deallocates the storage referenced by the pointer `p`, which must be a pointer obtained by an earlier call to `allocate()`. The argument `n` must be equal to the second argument of the call to `allocate()` that originally produced `p`.

That is, you can't deallocate a part of the storage that you allocated, only the whole chunk.

The solution would be to not return the storage that is made free by the call to `erase`. Just update your member iterators accordingly so that you keep this storage avaliable for subsequent calls to `create`. This is what the standard container `vector` does, too.

If you really want to return excess storage, allocate a smaller temporary chunk, copy the elements that are staying in the container there, release the old storage and update iterators.

Thing to bear in mind here is exception safety. Once you allocate a temporary buffer, you need to make sure you don't leak it in case an exception occurs during copying of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

As jrok and the others have mentioned, you cannot deallocate part of the memory - you'll need to deallocate the [entire referenced storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate).

There's one more important thing - if you look through Chapter 11 (specifically, under 11.4, *Dynamic Vecs*), you'll notice that the implementation for `push_back()` doubles the size of the underlying array once it reaches the current maximum size.

On similar lines, you'd want to *halve* the size of the underlying array when the size of your vector becomes *one-fourth* of the current maximum size. This is when you'd need to reallocate memory and call `std::allocator::deallocate` to release the excess storage.